# Get user region/town with woocommerce geolocate

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, geolocation

I have tried using woocommerce geolocate and it's only returning the country as shown below

```
function custom_use_geolocated_user_country(){
// Geolocation must be enabled @ Woo Settings
$location = WC_Geolocation::geolocate_ip();
echo $location;
}
```

Its returning only the country as shown below

[image]

I have tried using other methods of `WC_Geolocation` Class like `geolocate_ip()` to get the customer IP address to use with external API services like https://ipinfo.io, which seems close to what I need.

[image]

From the image above, I need to get exact region in FCT like Gwarimpa, Kuje, Garki, etc.

Any idea to how to achieve this or getting the customer postcode is welcomed.

Comment: Detailed geolocation requires geolocation provider with extended **commercial** API access…

Comment: Do you know any geolocation provider with extended commercial API access?

Comment: May be you can try to search and find [geolocation plugins for wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/geolocation/) or [some plugins for WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/product-category/woocommerce-extensions/?utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=search%20prospecting&utm_campaign=woocommerce%20extensions&utm_term=woocommerce%20%2Bplugins) that allow extended features as you required. Certainly some of them requires a registration license that extend their features.